# Ideal Directory for global npm install on CentOS 7

Tags: node.js, npm, centos

I have a CentOS 7 production installation that installs global packages in `/root/node_modules`. Thus, they won't be globally available on the system. npm root also confirms this. Of course, I could probably install with prefix, or any similar NVM-ish hack; but I'd rather not.

I also tried installing globally required packages as local `devDependencies`. One side effect was that pm2 cluster module was not spawning processes on all my cores, as I've seen on my other CentOS development server, and I've installed and used node/npm on more systems than I care to count, the majority being Linux/CentOS machines.

NPM [states](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) that global packages will be saved "in `/usr/local` or wherever node is installed." That's what I expect, so I try tweaking the config editor a bit to no luck. It seems that no matter what I do, global packages are saved in `/root/node_modules`, and cannot be located across the system with `which nodemon` for instance. I posted this question [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1393305/npm-installing-global-packages-in-root-node-modules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm root` will print the directory where it would install files.

> Print the effective node_modules folder to standard out.

If you are in `~root` this will be `/root/node_modules`

however you can also query where global files are located, with the global argument switch:

`npm -g root` and this will resolve to `/usr/lib/node_modules` or similar. `npm -g install ..` will install packages to that global install directory.

In case you want to have local packages at a globally available path, you could install to your filesystem root. `cd /` and from there `npm install ..` all users would have read access to that folder by default. Node will find those packages.

The `whitch` command would find binary files that are in your `$PATH`, not really npm packages. You can create symlinks in your `\bin` and use npm-packaged global binaries, for example CLI commands.

Note: On modern distros with systemd, you should write systemd services instead of running nodemon, especially if you have many systems running permanently.